# Web APIs are not working after upgrade comiplesdkversion 32 to 33 in android

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

When i am trying to upgrade compileSdkVersion 32 to 33 and minifyenabled true in release mode web apis are not working. If anyone have solutions please post here. Thanks in advance.

```
compileSdkVersion 33
buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.abcd"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 33
}
```

Comment: Can you send me error what is the issue.

Comment: Please include the relevant code parts and the error message you get into your question.

Comment: I am unable to get erro in release build. I have implemented solution from https://arunpandianm.medium.com/6-daily-issues-in-android-cleartext-traffic-error-52ab31dd86c2 but still not working @Robert